# ProLiant Gen8 Microsoft BIOS records 8GB put POST only shows 4GB

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant, bios

I've got a HP Proliant Micro Gen 8 server. I've had it a while with 1 4GB RAM stick installed. I've now installed another 4GB RAM stick, its the same type, except its not an HP genuine stick (presumably this doesn't matter).

When you look in the iLO it reports both RAM sticks installed and working fine as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: ILO Memory Details]

In the BIOS configuration it also shows that there is 8GB RAM installed as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: BIOS Memory Details]

But during POST and when the OS has booted (Vmware ESXi) it shows only 4GB as being available as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: POST Details]

I've never seen this before, I've seen it where the additional memory is not detected at all but it is and shown is installed, but POST and OS showing as if it doesn't exist.

I've tried going into the Intelligent Provisioning for the first time, and found it doesn't work, goes to a grub menu for some reason, so I'm hoping the answer to fixing this doesn't result in going into the intelligent provisioning.

Comment: Hi, the memory was slotted into the correct bank ? not in the second cpu bank in example, as your system got only one cpu from the screen I seen

Comment: Hi @yagmoth555, the motherboard only has space for 1 CPU and just has the two DIMM slots

Comment: Update to the latest BIOS, if the ram is in fact the same type e.g. un/registered under/buffered those MUST match

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have mixed registered and unregistered. That won't work. All the ram needs to be registered or unregistered.

Comment: Where are you seeing that?

Comment: @Boardy https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymL1q.png

Comment: Last column of the iLO report.

Comment: Ah damn didn't notice that. Checked everything else before buying it and forgot about the registered and unregistered

Comment: For some reason I've now bought another DIMM module exactly the same and now it get stuck on boot with status code 0114

Comment: @Boardy is it a 64-bit processor?

Comment: It probably only likes server ram, not consumer ram

Comment: @cat It is yea, its a Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU G1610T @ 2.30GHz, it doesn't look like the server supports RDIMM, only UDIMM annoyingly. Didn't realise there was that restriction, thought as long as it matched didn't matter